# How to Increment Count of Shared Ptr from Raw Ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, googletest, googlemock

I am working on class unit testing and encountered this problem - a premature deletion of `Device* device`/mock:

Here is my SUT:

```
Effect::~Effect()
{
    for (auto it = infoList.begin(); it != infoList.end(); ++it)
    {
         (*it)->device->Remove(this, (*it)->position);
         delete *it;
    }
    infoList.clear();
}

HRESULT Effect::Add(Device* device, ULONG position)
{
    Info* info = new Info;
    info->device = device;
    info->position= position;

    auto result = device->Add(position);
    if (result == E_FAIL) return E_FAIL;

    //some other methods being called from 'device'

    infoList.push_back(info);
}
```

And my test:

```
class EffectTest: public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    void SetUp()
    {
        sut_ = std::make_unique<Effect>();
        deviceMock_ = std::make_shared<DeviceMock>();
    }

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<Effect> sut_;
    std::shared_ptr<DeviceMock> deviceMock_;
};


TEST_F(EffectTest, Add)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*deviceMock_, Add(_).WillRepeatedly(Return(S_OK));
    EXPECT_CALL(*deviceMock_, Remove(_, _)).WillRepeatedly(Return(S_OK));

    sut_->Add(deviceMock_.get(), 90);
}
```

Since I am only passing a raw pointer (mock) `deviceMock_.get()` in Effect::Add(), reference count is not incremented. Test tears down earlier than the actual SUT so deviceMock_ is already deleted when Effect destructor is called.  My problem is.. device is still being called in Effect's destructor and therefore causes a crash:

```
(*it)->device->Remove(this, (*it)->position);
```

Any thoughts on what I can do to force the `deviceMock_` to stay alive when `~Effect` is called?
Can I force deviceMock_ reference count to increment only with the raw pointer `Device* device`??

Please do note though that **I CANNOT CHANGE THE FUNCTION SIGNATURE** OF:

```
HRESULT Effect::Add(Device* device, ULONG position)
```

Since this is an **API**.

Help please! Thanks!

Comment: Bad situation. Can you hold an extra `shared_ptr` around the resp. calls? From raw pointer to `shared_ptr` - IMHO difficult. (The opposite approach would be not to take ownership with `shared_ptr` if it is internally managed in some other way.)

Comment: I tried adding a local shared_ptr for Effect class: 
```extraSharedPtr.reset(device);``` thinking I can increase the reference count of ```deviceMock_``` but well, it does not (which makes sense).. So I am out of ideas now.. Any ideas @Scheff?

Comment: From your sources, I'm not quite sure what owns what. However, `std::shared_ptr` and `delete` are IMHO completely contradictory. Either you take life-time control or you pass it to `shared_ptr`. Mixing it is a bad idea - but that's what you already know. If the API dictates a life-time control in any other way, then you shouldn't use `shared_ptr` from outside.

Comment: Sounds like you will be needing something like `shared_from_this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the order of `sut_` and `deviceMock_` in `EffectTest`:

```
class EffectTest: public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    void SetUp()
    {
        sut_ = std::make_unique<Effect>();
        deviceMock_ = std::make_shared<DeviceMock>();
    }

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<DeviceMock> deviceMock_;
    std::unique_ptr<Effect> sut_;
};
```

Member variables are deleted from bottom to top. Changing this will cause Effect to be deleted before DeviceMock.

Comment: Wow, this is the quickest solution! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to fix this issue. Basically, I changed scope of `sut_` from class level to test level:

```
class EffectTest: public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    void SetUp()
    {
        deviceMock_ = std::make_shared<DeviceMock>();
    }

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<DeviceMock> deviceMock_;
};


TEST_F(EffectTest, Add)
{
    auto sut_ = std::make_unique<Effect>();  //THIS IS THE FIX!

    EXPECT_CALL(*deviceMock_, Add(_).WillRepeatedly(Return(S_OK));
    EXPECT_CALL(*deviceMock_, Remove(_, _)).WillRepeatedly(Return(S_OK));

    sut_->Add(deviceMock_.get(), 90);
}
```

This way, `sut_` gets destructed first vs the mock.